# Induction rule case names (Isabelle)

Tags: isabelle, induction

Some induction rules have case names: the default one has `case 0` and `case (Suc n)` for example. Given a rule, e.g. `int_induct`, how do I find out its case names (if, indeed, it has these) without looking in the theory containing this lemma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any high-level way to do this. The case names are stored in the *tags* of a theorem that can be obtained with ML:

```
ML‹Thm.get_tags @{thm nat.induct}›
```

This prints:

```
val it = [("name", "Nat.nat.induct"), ("kind", "theorem"), ("case_names", "zero;Suc")]: Properties.T
```

As you can see, the case names are available under the key `case_names`.

Comment: You can also use `Rule_Cases.get`, e.g. `ML_val ‹Rule_Cases.get @{thm nat.induct}›`. And, of course, you can just use the rule in Isar and then use `print_cases`.